# Word Automation reset numbering scheme

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am new in programming with C# and am working with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word extension. My program takes several Word Documents and inserts these into a single document. I am having trouble with resetting the numbering scheme in my document [Picture showing my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBFt0.png)

This is my code with which I am Inserting my Documents:

```
        word.Selection.InsertNewPage();
        Word.Paragraph para2;
        para2 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
        para2.Range.Text = "Vertrag";
        para2.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
        para2.Range.Font.Size = 24;
        para2.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
        para2.Format.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
        para2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        //Resetting the Font to normal
        word.Selection.GoTo(ref gotoPage, ref gotoLast, ref missing, ref missing);
        word.Selection.ClearFormatting();

        //ADDING THE FOURTH PAGE
        word.Selection.InsertNewPage();
        word.Selection.GoTo(ref gotoPage, ref gotoLast, ref missing, ref missing);
        doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref endOfDoc).Range.InsertFile(filePathLeist, ref missing, ref oFalse, ref oFalse, ref oFalse);
        word.Selection.GoTo(ref gotoPage, ref gotoLast, ref missing, ref missing);
        //word.Selection.ClearFormatting();


        //ADDING THE FIFTH PAGE
        word.Selection.GoTo(ref gotoPage, ref gotoLast, ref missing, ref missing);
        word.Selection.InsertNewPage();
        string filePathAGB = filePathCommon + "\\effexx_WSIV_allgemein_AGB_2020_V1_0.docx";
        doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref endOfDoc).Range.InsertFile(filePathAGB, ref missing, ref oFalse, ref oFalse, ref oFalse);
```

I tried clearing the formatting between the two documents but that didn't work
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and what can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This might be better done in a comment but I am also new here and not allowed to comment yet.

The following page, although old, should be helpful: [Methods for Restarting Numbering Using vba by Margaret Aldis, Word MVP](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Numbering/ListRestartMethods.htm)

Looking at your code, it looks good to me, but automatic numbering in Word is messed up. This has been true for more than twenty-five years. [Word Numbering Explained by John McGhie, MVP](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Numbering/WordsNumberingExplained.htm) There are two solid methods that are pretty much unbreakable. The first is attaching a numbering scheme to paragraph styles, one for each level as set forth in Shauna Kelly's tutorial "[How to create numbered headings or outline numbering in Word](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html)." If your numbering in the your documents is tied to the same styles, it should integrate seamlessly.

The second method has been around for more than 25 years and is to use Sequence Fields. That one works wonderfully but would have to be set up the same way in each documents.

To fix document numbering in multiple documents to be using the same method through code is beyond my abilities. Anyone attempting it would need to know how the numbering is set up currently, I expect. Margaret Aldis suggests "you can create the list template and link each level to the appropriate style using a VBA macro." If I were attempting this, I would create a template with those styles and then transfer the styles to the document using the [OrganizerCopy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.organizercopy) and go through the numbering in the document applying the appropriate styles to the various numbered paragraphs in the document. This, though, would likely make a mess of any formatting of those paragraphs. [Using the Organizer in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Organizer). An [example of a template that can do this](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#GlobalStylesheet) can be downloaded from my site.

To make this easy in the future, you would want to have a document template in Word that is used as the basis for new documents that have to be merged. This template should have a numbering scheme set up and that should be used in each of the documents. I would recommend Shauna's method. To use it, your users should use the appropriate styles to apply the numbering, not the buttons on the Home tab.

Note that when discussing Word, the term "Template" is a term or art or jargon. Do not read it as having the usual meaning in ordinary English. [Templates in Microsoft Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm)

If using Sequence fields, you could have the field stored in AutoText or some sort of Building Block. This is described in my [page on numbering](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields).